# SAP HANA Calculation Engine CE_OLAP_VIEW failes

Tags: hana

When I try to use code given below to create a scripted calculation view, I get the following error (BTW, I have also tried using sum("NET_SALES") as well as specifying the schema with similar result.

Message :
    Internal deployment of object failed;Repository: Encountered an error in repository runtime extension;Internal Error:Deploy Calculation View: SQL: transaction rolled back by an internal error: invalid table name:  Could not find table/view AV_EXPO_SALES in schema SYSTEM: line 4294967295 col 4294967295 (at pos 4294967295)nSet Schema DDL statement: set schema "SYSTEM"nType DDL: create type "_SYS_BIC"."SK/SK_TEST_SCRIPT/proc/tabletype/VAR_OUT" as table ("ITEM_NAME_1" VARCHAR(100), "SALES_AMOUNT_1" DECIMAL(12,2))nProcedure DDL: create procedure "_SYS_BIC"."SK/SK_TEST_SCRIPT/proc" ( OUT var_out "_SYS_BIC"."SK/SK_TEST_SCRIPT/proc/tabletype/VAR_OUT" ) language sqlscript sql security definer reads sql data as  n /********* Begin Procedure Script ************/ n BEGIN n t var_out = CE_OLAP_VIEW("AV_EXPO_SALES",["CUSTOMER_NAME","NET_SALES"]);nnEND /********* End Procedure Script ************/n

code:

```
BEGIN 
     var_out = CE_OLAP_VIEW("AV_EXPO_SALES",["CUSTOMER_NAME","NET_SALES"]);

END
```

Answer (score 1):

The activated information views are always located in schema `_SYS_BIC`.
So something like

```
BEGIN 
     var_out = CE_OLAP_VIEW("_SYS_BIC"."AV_EXPO_SALES",["CUSTOMER_NAME","NET_SALES"]);

END;
```

should work.

- Lars